# Is there a name for encoding a sequence of bytes as differences from the previous byte?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, binary, compression

For example, encoding `00 01 02 03 06 07 08 09` as `00 01 01 01 03 01 01 01` to increase the effectiveness of applying a compression algorithm to the data (e.g. run-length encoding)?

Such an encoding could be decoded using:

```
temp = 0
for byte in encoded:
    temp += byte
    decoded.append(temp)
```

Comment: I've seen this called "predictive filtering", a kind of "transform" -- http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_561

Answer (score 3):

[Delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) is similar to your description.

> Delta encoding is a way of storing or transmitting data in the form of
>   differences (deltas) between sequential data rather than complete
>   files.

Comment: That's the closest thing I found as well - but Wikipedia seems to describe delta encoding only in terms of differences between files, rather than between bytes in a single file?

Comment: As I understand, Delta encoding is just a generic definition that can be applied depend on the situations.

For your case : You calculate different between 2 bytes.
But it can also be between 2 files, 2 frames of a video, ...
It's really just depend on the way you chose your "unit" of data

Comment: You could call it "Byte-level delta encoding" if you wanted to, but @thienDX's answer is the correct one. What you call something is arbitrary and coalesces around the terms people (like you!) actually use.